# jQuery post form onclick (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

**EDIT!**

Can I change this javascript into a click function? When click div id "foo" ?

**HTML**

```
<form id="mall" action="" method="post">
<input name="title" type="text" />
<input name="email" type="text" />

<div id="foo">Click on me to submit</div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

This works with an ordinary submit button. Can I make this a .click function to the div?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mall").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('process.php', $("#mall").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });

            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: why you need different buttons

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but I don't think this will result in good UX

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

updated to edit:

I'm thinking your code is a bit awkward, you should use a `<button>Click me to submit</button>` or a `<input type="submit" value="Click me" />` instead of a `div` but I'm giving you the solution to your question

```
$("#foo").click(function(){
  $(this).closest("form").submit()
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It didn't work though. Please view my edit

Comment: @HundkartanJonas updated, please know that conventionally you should use a `<input type="submit" />` button in your case, but you might have other intentions so I'm answering your question as is